# Finding a connection between two cities

Tags: algorithm

I have a hypothetical problem. Let's assume I have a bunch of cities which are connected in a way with each other. The question is purely hypothetical so it doesn't matter how we connect them (we can think of them as some kind of graph). Between the cities are bus connections, but these connections aren't very reliable. They add or remove a random time to the time we would expect them to leave a city, and the time they arrive to the other one. How do I find a way to bring a person from one city to another as fast as possible / relatively fast but with a bigger probability?
What kind of algorithms should I read about to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very difficult problem that can be approached in a game-theoretic manner.

The best paper that comes to mind is [Multi-modal Journey Planning in the Presence of Uncertainty](http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/ICAPS/ICAPS13/paper/download/6023/6159) by Botea *et. al*

The gist of the paper is this:

- Each mode of transportation (walk, bus, or taxi) has some range of times it takes to get you to your destination, with associated probabilities.
- You need to be at place X by time Y, so you assume the worst case for each mode of transportation
- Assuming the worst, you take the route with the highest probability of getting you there on time.

So if a taxi takes between 60-90 minutes to get you to your destination, but a bus takes 70 always, and you need to get to your destination in the next 80 minutes, you'd take the bus.

However, if you need to get to your destination in the next 65 minutes, you take the taxi, because it's the only mode that could possibly get you there on time.

I'm thinking you could adapt their approach to yours. Each city is connected to K other cities via bus routes that have their own associated durations and probabilities of those durations. You could think of each bus route as a different mode of transportation.

---

Another approach is to use A* on your graph, where your heuristic seeks to minimize uncertainty and duration.

A relevant paper to this second approach (not quite the same, but related) is [FIRM: Feedback controller-based Information-state Roadmap - A framework for motion planning under uncertainty](http://dnc.tamu.edu/wiki/images/f/f6/FIRM_IROS_2011.pdf).

While this paper covers a lot about dynamical systems, the part about extracting a path through the roadmap (graph) to minimize uncertainty would be useful. Perhaps you could adapt this to incorporate some aspect of speed.

Comment: I chose this answer, because it linked to useful papers. But I'd like to thank you for all your answers.

Answer (score 1):

If the variation is truly random, then to me it seems like the best thing you could do would be to find the path with the least number of connections. This can be accomplished with a [Breadth First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at routing algorithms like the [Distance Vector Routing Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance-vector_routing_protocol). They are intended for this exact purpose. Find a way to other nodes, even if the graph changes.
A short summary of what you could do would be the following:

- Each city stores a list of all cities it reaches. Along with that it stores the distance and through which neighbor node it reaches the city. Each city then tells its neighbors which nodes it can reach. If the newly received informations of the neighbors change the current possible connections, the city updates its list and propagates this information to the others, untill the list does not change anymore.
- Every time a city notices that a connection to a neighbor is broken or recovered, it updates the list and transmits this information to all its remaining neighbors. Each neighbor then updates their list and propagates the information to its other neighbors.
- Be aware of the "count to infinity problem"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a possible **solution** for such a problem. However, in a world of randomness (e.g. real world) where each your move can fail, there is a model for that. Try to use Discrete Time Markov Chain (DTMC).

Each your city is a Markov State.
When you try to move from city A to city B there is a probability of success and failure.
Failure means you stay in the same city.

With DTMC you can calculate how many moves you need to make, to achieve your final city with some probability.